# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane$1 (wrong name: javafx/scene/control/ScrollPaned1)

Tags: java, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

On the following code:

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
```

I get an exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane$1 (wrong name: javafx/scene/control/ScrollPaned1)
```

What does it mean? Especially, what does it mean "wrong name" addition?

**UPDATE**

Class is the part of the JRE, inside `jfxrt.jar`, so renaming file is not an option. Additionally filename is correct.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you try to run with another JRE?

Comment: No. Even the same project sometimes runs well after various modifications. My wish is to understand the sense of an error

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the file name is invalid, or isn't the same as the class name, have you tried renaming the file where the ScrollPane class is defined to ScrollPane.java?

Comment: It's library file, part of the JRE